# How can i delete gap on 2 clip pathed div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have 2 clip-pathed div and they are so far from each other. How can I make it come closer?
My codepen :  https://codepen.io/ugurcanTheReactDev/pen/BawLzdB?editors=1100
To make it more clear I have a photo like :

[image]

As you can see they are far from each other. I need to make them nearly together with so small a gap.
My codes :

HTML :

```
<div className="flex gap-1 h-72 mt-2">
          <div className="exploreAreaDiv">  //First one.
            <div className="exploreAreaDivOverlay">
              <h1 className="text-4xl text-gray-100">EXPLORE THE AREA</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="covid-div " style={{ flex: 0.6 }}> //2nd one
            <div className="covid-div-overlay">
              <h1 className="text-4xl text-gray-100">EXPLORE THE AREA</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .exploreAreaDiv {
      flex: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 96% 0, 83% 100%, 0 100%);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Love_Antalya.jpg");
    }
    .exploreAreaDivOverlay {
  background-color: rgba(43, 42, 42, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 96% 0, 83% 100%, 0 100%);
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -100vw;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
    .exploreAreaDiv:hover .exploreAreaDivOverlay {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .covid-div {
      width: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
       
      background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
      clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 3% 100%);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-image: url("https://sedefed.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/coronavirus-4914026_1920.jpg");
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: please add all classes you have used and add your code in the snippet for better understanding.

Comment: @ækit okay brother. I added few more. If i add more system doesnt accept it. Others is same too covid-div-overlay is same as exploreAreaDivOverlay. flex / gap-1 / mt-2 is coming from tailwindcss they are basicly doing like : display:Flex / gap:2px / margin-top:4px etc.

Comment: you can show your code in codepen like [this](https://codepen.io/ankitcodes/pen/yLzaOqL?editors=1100). as much I know the problem is in clip-path: polygon(). I think you have to change some parameters. but share code in code so that everyone understands.

Comment: @ækit oh you are totally right! I add my codepen link to post now thanks for reply!

Comment: To some extend you can reduce by changing the clip path.  
exploreAreaDiv : clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 92% 100%, 0 100%);
covid-div: polygon(14% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about clip-path but what actually happened is those two dives are in contact with each other and can't go over.

in the image, there is a dotted line that shows dives size.

[image]

---

- what you have to do is make them overlap each other for some pixel or percentage.
- if you don't want to make them overlap you can remove the image of one of the div and make it transparent then set the image to the parent div (flex gap-1 h-72 mt-2).

here I added `transform: translateX(10%);` in `.exploreAreaDiv{}` and `transform: translateX(-10%);` in `.covid-div{}`. i kept little space which looks good but you can remove it properly but setting `transform: translateX(13%);` and `transform: translateX(-13%);`.

```css
.h-72{
  height:200px;
}
.flex{
  display:flex;
}
.gap-1{
  
}

.exploreAreaDiv {
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 0 100%);
  transform: translateX(10%);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Love_Antalya.jpg");
}
.exploreAreaDivOverlay {
  background-color: rgba(43, 42, 42, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 0 100%);
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -100vw;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.exploreAreaDiv:hover .exploreAreaDivOverlay {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.covid-div {
  width: 100%;
  flex:0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative; 
  background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
  transform: translateX(-10%);
  clip-path: polygon(33% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://sedefed.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/coronavirus-4914026_1920.jpg");
}

.covid-div-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(43, 42, 42, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(33% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-right: -100vw;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.covid-div:hover .covid-div-overlay {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex gap-1 h-72 mt-2">
          <div class="exploreAreaDiv">  
            <div class="exploreAreaDivOverlay">
              <h1 class="text-4xl text-gray-100">EXPLORE THE AREA</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="covid-div "> 
            <div class="covid-div-overlay">
              <h1 class="text-4xl text-gray-100">EXPLORE THE AREA</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

you can try other transform properties like `transform: scaleX(1.2);` or `transform: skewX(10deg);` but for using skew you have to make changes or have to remove the clip-path.